# UrlRewriteFilter run element produces 404 but to element works fine on GAE/Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

I'm using the UrlRewriteFilter library in order to avoid having to write my own url filter.

I'm pretty sure that I have things set up properly, because when I have this in my url rewrite xml:

```
    <rule>
      <from>^/urlIWantToMap</from>
      <to type="redirect">/WhereIWouldLikeItToGo</to>
    </rule>
```

It seems to work fine (as in, hitting http://localhost:8080/urlIWantToMap sends me to the intended location).  Note that I had to add the servlet mapping to my web.xml.

If I try this though...

```
    <rule>
      <from>^/urlIWantToMap</from>
      <run class="mypackage.MyServletClass" method="doGet"/>
    </rule>
```

I get an http 404.  I think it is the same kind of problem described here (even though I'm suspicious on the solution/resolution the author comes to):

http://greatwebguy.com/programming/java/urlrewritefilter-servlet-filter-problem-in-websphere-6105-and-greater/

I can see this happening if there were some kind of change to web filter behavior that would inhibit UrlRewriteFilter from calling into the servlet.  Either that; or I'm making a blatant mistake I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see something like this when the application server starts?

```
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Run ERROR: could not find method with the name doGet on mypackage.MyServletClass
```

Even if you don't, does a **public** method doGet exist without any parameters? In my case it was protected, and while http://localhost:8080/MyProject/rewrite-status told me everthing was fine, I still got a 404.

I had to create a wrapper method to make doGet public and configure urlrewrite.xml like this:

```
<run class="my.wrappers.WrapperServlet" method="doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)" />
```

Comment: I've since moved on without this; but I'll go back and give it a shot when I get the chance.