# Why isn't my UrlRewriteFilter working on Tomcat?

Tags: apache, web-applications, tomcat

**Summary**

I am having trouble getting UrlRewriteFilter up and running on Tomcat.

**Problem**

I can only get one of the two rules from the default urlrewrite.xml file to work. I followed the [installation directions](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html#install) without much of a problem and I haven't changed any defaults or messed with the configuration file.

**Example**

The outbound rule works: http://localhost:8080/mysite/rewrite-status successfully takes me to a description page of my urlrewrite.xml file.

But the regular rule doesn't work: http://localhost:8080/mysite/test/status does not redirect me to http://localhost:8080/mysite/rewrite-status. I get a 404 result.

Am I expecting the wrong thing from these rules? What could be wrong?

**Details**

Here is the urlrewrite.xml file that comes with the installation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.2//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.2.dtd">

<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
        <note>
            The rule means that requests to /test/status/ will be redirected to /rewrite-status
            the url will be rewritten.
        </note>
        <from>/test/status/</from>
        <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/rewrite-status</to>
    </rule>


    <outbound-rule>
        <note>
            The outbound-rule specifies that when response.encodeURL is called (if you are using JSTL c:url)
            the url /rewrite-status will be rewritten to /test/status/.

            The above rule and this outbound-rule means that end users should never see the
            url /rewrite-status only /test/status/ both in their location bar and in hyperlinks
            in your pages.
        </note>
        <from>/rewrite-status</from>
        <to>/test/status/</to>
    </outbound-rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: I asked a very similar question; but haven't had the time to test the one answer I got.  You can check it out and see if the info is useful though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218909/urlrewritefilter-run-element-produces-404-but-to-element-works-fine-on-gae-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does adding or removing trailing forward slash (/) make a difference? Could experiment with setting it in both or either for the from and to tags of rule tag set.

Answer (score 1):

@Mike is right, change

```
<from>/test/status/</from>
```

to

```
<from>/test/status</from>
```